# How can I play chunked video using react-native-video?

Tags: react-native, mp4, react-native-video, chunked, range-requests

We are developing application such as Tiktok where we are using Flatlist to list videos and using react-native-video library to display videos.

Now, whenever our video is big such as 50 MB or 100 MB, react-native-video is taking too much time to load video.

How can we apply range request to MP4 video within react-natice-video to get chunk of MP4 file rather than getting whole video.

In backend we are using AWS Cloudfront and it supports range request for MP4 videos.